# How to validate email address in iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, email-validation

My main goal is to check if the input of a text field is correct (i.e., email address). I found many `emailIsValid` sort of functions online but I think I am thinking about this wrong, yes I do want to check if the email is correct but I also do want to check if the email is not correct. The function works fine but is there a way I can set the parameters to say (if `(`self.isEmailValid (userEmail != true))`) so it also checks at the same time if the email doesn't meet the constraints and throws an alert, like the one I built in.

My code works fine but it does not work how I want it to work, I am basically trying to throw an error when the email is not valid. What should I change in the else if statement to achieve this, or am I going about this all wrong?

Beginner in swift.

```
@IBAction  func sendEmail(sender: AnyObject){

    let userEmail = emailTextField.text

    if (userEmail!.isEmpty){

        let myAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Alert",
        message: "Email field is required to continue.",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

        myAlert.addAction(okAction)

        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    else if self.isValidEmail(userEmail!){

        let myAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Alert",
        message: "Email field is required to continue.",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

        myAlert.addAction(okAction)

        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

}

func isValidEmail(enteredEmail:String) -> Bool {

    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    return emailPredicate.evaluateWithObject(enteredEmail)

}
```

Comment: `else if !self.isValidEmail(userEmail!)` do you mean if it's not valid? just add `!` before `self.isValidEma...`

Comment: `if (userEmail!.isEmpty || !self.isValidEmail(userEmail!)){
    // your error

}

Comment: Thank you so much guys, thats what I was missing!

Comment: Is there a more recent way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this. Avoid using force unwraps with the !. Better use a guard let statement and do proper error handling.

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: UITextField) {

    guard let userEmail = sender.text else {
        errorAlert()
        return 
    }

    if isValidEmail(userEmail) {
        //do your login stuff
    } else {
        errorAlert()
    }
}

func isValidEmail(enteredEmail: String) -> Bool {
    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    return emailPredicate.evaluateWithObject(enteredEmail)
}

func errorAlert() {
    //put your alert controller here
}
```